# Switching over from Xtal to variable oscillator with minimal hardware?

Tags: oscillator, crystal, switching

I have an old circuit with an 8bit Z80 CPU. The oscillator circuit is a standard Xtal with two load caps. I'm interested in slowing down the operation of the circuit with a tune-able oscillator which I did and it works as expected (more or less).

Question is - I'm controlling the variable oscillator using a potentiometer and switch-over is done using a toggle switch which lifts one leg of the Xtal and connects the variable oscillator's output instead. I would like to integrate everything to a single potentiometer due to lack of space for another button.

The digital approach would evolve a reed relay, digital pot, mcu, encoder and I am trying to make something minimal. If anyone has suggestions for a better circuit please let me know.

Comment: "I would like to integrate everything to a single potentiometer due to lack of space for another button" you lost me after that part.... what are you trying to do...

Comment: I think I can see what you want. You want your pot' to control two things: (1) the adjustable frequency (2) selection between adjustable frequency or fixed crystal. Can you fit a pot' in there with an end-stop switch, like the old radios with the off/on and volume all in one pot'? Then, if you've space for it, the pot' switch can control switch-over electronics and you can use an oscillator module instead of the crystal. I'm assuming (horrible word) that your space confinements for an accessible pot' might be different to those for circuitry. Please edit info' into question, not as comments.

Answer (score 2):

If the microprocessor contains its own oscillator, requiring only an external crystal (not an oscillator module), it isn't really necessary to disconnect the crystal. It has a high impedance at the low frequency of your slow-speed oscillator and does not affect its operation.

So, a simple "volume control with on-off switch" could be used as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnPDQw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch is open, the crystal oscillator works normally, as long as the wiring between it and the switch does not introduce too much stray capacitance. When the switch is closed, the oscillator easily overpowers the crystal, and the frequency of operation can be adjusted by the potentiometer.

If the wire between the switch and the crystal cannot be kept short, use the switch to control a relay that is closer to the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you get a  cheap simple divider chip with built in osc like say a HC4060 and connect your crystal to it .There are lots of outputs that could be switched to give very slow operation .The key here is that for your job you do not need continiously variable frequency but want a big dynamic range .The divider chip will give less construction hassles than a VFO and is much easier than DDS .

Comment: Interesting idea!